# What does "Clocked their goal" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I'm translating a book about behavior. What does  "Clocked their goal" mean in the following context:

> They agreed to delegate more of the “old work” to sub-ordinates. They even clocked their goal: 30 percent fewer hours per team member on paperwork.

I guessed it means "set their goal". Is that correct?

Comment: I guess yes, the meaning might be: "they set their goal in terms of hours" (roughly speaking). You can set a goal in terms of "less sheets of paper processed by a team member" -- that would not be "clocking your goal", because you've expressed your goal in sheets of paper, not in hours.

Answer (score 1):

To "clock" something means to **'time it'**. Or it could simply mean **'to measure'** or **'to quantify'**.

> The car clocked the lap in a minute fifty.

This means that the car finished the lap in a time of 1:50.

Here, *"30 percent fewer hours...."* is the "clocked" value. So it means "to measure".

Also, "clocked" also means **'to notice'**. [Check this out.](https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=clocked%20meaning)

Answer (score 1):

The meaning is more about **measuring time**.

> They **clocked** their goal
>   They **measured the time** to attain their goal

It probably comes from the phrase **on the clock** when people had to **punch in** and **punch out** on a time clock in factories.